# Selecionar data a partir da data atual usando pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou trabalhando em um projeto simples para um hostel, no site tem um pequeno formulário de solicitação de estádia. Nele tem dois campos para selecionar a data de entrada e outro para selecionar a data de saída.
Eu estou usando a biblioteca http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ pois já trabalho com ela a um bom tempo.

O problema é que não estou encontrando uma forma para que o segundo input onde irá carregar a data de saída, seja maior que a data selecionada no campo de chegada, igualmente tem nesses sites de compras de passagens. alguém me da uma luz?

```js
$('.data1').pickadate({
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  closeOnSelect: true,
  closeOnClear: true,
  monthsFull: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  weekdaysFull: ['domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira', 'sábado'],
  weekdaysShort: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],
  today: 'hoje',
  clear: 'limpar',
  close: 'fechar',
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('.data2').pickadate({
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  closeOnSelect: true,
  closeOnClear: true,
  monthsFull: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  weekdaysFull: ['domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira', 'sábado'],
  weekdaysShort: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],
  today: 'hoje',
  clear: 'limpar',
  close: 'fechar',
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://parahybahostel.com.br/js/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://parahybahostel.com.br/js/picker.date.js"></script>

<link href="https://parahybahostel.com.br/css/classic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://parahybahostel.com.br/css/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form method="POST">
  Entrada:
  <input type="text" name="chegada" class="data1" value="" />
  <br />
  <br /> Saída:
  <input type="text" name="saida" class="data2" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: está utilizando alguma linguagem bakc-end? pode incluir parte do código para testarmos ?

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 não estou usando não, eu inserir o código, como vc pode ver, a biblioteca já exibe todo o calendário

Comment: você quer que quando selecionar a primeira data a segunda não possa ser colocada caso seja selecionado uma data menor que a primeira ?

Comment: isso mesmo, igual neste exemplo aqui https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Nesse caso acho que minha resposta seria útil porem não do jeito que você queria, pera aê

Comment: Exato, funcionou, mas não da forma que eu queria rs, estou tentando aqui adaptar mas não consigo pegar o valor do ID data1 e usar no parâmetro min

Comment: ja desenvolvi o codigo pra vc, estou postando a resposta

Comment: ja postei uma solução

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o min: new Date() no  formato YYYY/MM/DD
Consulte a documentação [aqui e veja exemplos](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#limits)

```
$('.data1').pickadate({
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  min: new Date(2017,11,28), // defina aqui adata de hoje
  closeOnSelect: true,
  closeOnClear: true,
  monthsFull: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 
 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 
 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  weekdaysFull: ['domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 
 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira', 'sábado'],
  weekdaysShort: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],
  today: 'hoje',
  clear: 'limpar',
  close: 'fechar',
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: O problema é que não seria a data de hoje, tem como jogar o valor da primeira data, que seria a data de chegada aí dentro? pois imagine que a pessoa selecione a data 20/12 ela não podere selecionar na data de sair uma data igual ou inferior a 20/12